# 1054 - Unknown column 'customers_group_id' in 'field list'

Tags: oscommerce

Can some please help me with this and tell me what to do to fix this?

This is the error message that I am getting

1054 - Unknown column 'customers_group_id' in 'field list'
SELECT customers_group_id FROM customers WHERE customers_id="4"

Comment: Can you share your table's structure?

Comment: Table
action_recorder, 
address_book ,
address_format, 
administrators,
banners 
banners_history 
categories 
categories_description 
configuration 
configuration_group 
counter 
counter_history 
countries 
currencies 
customers 
customers_basket 
customers_basket_attributes 
customers_info 
featured 
geo_zones 
languages 
manufacturers 
manufacturers_info 
newsletters 
orders 
orders_products 
orders_products_attributes 
orders_products_download 
orders_status 
orders_status_history 
orders_total

Comment: products 
products_attributes 
products_attributes_download 
products_description 
products_images 
products_notifications 
products_options 
products_options_values 
products_options_values_to_products_options 
products_related_products 
products_tags 
products_to_categories 
reviews 
reviews_description 
sec_directory_whitelist 
sessions 
specials 
tags 
tax_class 
tax_rates 
usu_cache 
whos_online 
zones 
zones_to_geo_zones

Comment: You'd need to add this information to your original post, properly formatted.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Separate Pricing Per Customer add-on was installed, but the database updates weren't made.  Try going through the documentation for SPPC, and find the SQL statements you need to run that adds the custom tables/columns to the database.

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: I did not have that contribution install, but it came with the new order edition contribution